# Tailwind css styles are not showing in my react app website when i deploy my repository

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment, tailwind-css, netlify

this is my first create react app website using tailwind css for styling, the styles work fine when i run the website locally, but when i deploy it in netlify all the styles are gone, i dont know where the problem is. please help

netlify site name: https://josevalen.netlify.app/
github repo: https://github.com/jmvr37/Personal-Website

i have tried almost everything and still nothing, no clue where the problem could be, it still building fine locally.[tailwindcss.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcMk3.png)

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "headroom.js": "^0.12.0",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.13",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-headroom": "^3.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "CI= react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

tailwindcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  purge: [  '/public/*.html',
  './src/components/**/*.{jsx,js}',],

  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'lg': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe You made mistake at this point =>

```
purge: ["/public/*.html", "./src/components/**/*.{jsx,js}"],
```

---

Try like this =>

```
purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
```

---

So finally Your file `tailwind.config.js` should look like this

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
    screens: {
      sm: "640px",
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      md: "768px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      lg: "1280px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Additionally, You can check the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) to see if You missed something..;-) Best Regards and good luck !

Comment: Thank you for the help, you were right the path was wrong, I appreciate your feedback. 

Comment: @Jose You're welcome;-) Glad I could help You.

Comment: @Jose To help the rest of the community it is helpful to mark the answer as correct.